# How to delay return callback until async task finishes?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

In the function I want to call return data after the onSuccessListener has finished execution.

```
private fun getFirebaseDataReturnsResult(
        fieldName: String,
        documentName: String,
        userUID: String) : String {

        var data : String? = null
        val docRef = db.collection(documentName).document(userUID)

        docRef.get(source)
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    data = document.getString(fieldName).toString()
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                        data = document?.getString(fieldName).toString()
                }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    data = exception.message.toString()
                }
            }
        return data!!
    }
```

`db` is an instance of Cloud Firestore.
`getFirebaseDataReturnsResult()` method is being called on `onViewCreated()` inside an IO coroutine scope.

I've tried adding `delay()` before returning data but I think that's just seems like bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docRef.get()` is asynchronous and returns a Task object immediately.  If you want to use this object in a coroutine, you should strongly consider making `getFirebaseDataReturnsResult` a `suspend fun` and converting that Task object to something you can await using [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services).  This will also save you the trouble of having to attach listeners to the Task, and you can just use try/catch instead.

Comment: Yeah that did work. I found this article that could help others with the same issue. https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-kotlin-coroutines-with-firebase-6f8577a3e00f